# testing Hibernate with Spring's EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder issues with SpringSessionContext

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing, junit4, spring-jdbc

I am unit-testing with Spring Framework's `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` as a datasource and passing this into the Hibernate config for my `SessionFactory`, using Spring 4 and Hibernate 4. *I am not using the Spring context in any way* - the only config I use is programmatic (no annotations, no XML except the Hibernate mapping files).

I expected that Hibernate would use its default `ThreadLocalSessionContext` and that I would be able to start and rollback transactions in the unit test.

However somehow Hibernate has set its `SessionFactory.currentSessionContext` to Spring's `SpringSessionContext` and this complains whenever I try to call `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`:

```
HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
```

In the code below in my unit test, I have set `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to **`thread`** but this is ignored or replaced with the Spring implementation.

```
public abstract class HibernateTestBase {

    private static EmbeddedDatabase dataSource;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        dataSource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().
                setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).
                addScript("file:SQLResources/schema-1.1.sql").
                addScript("file:SQLResources/schema-1.2.sql").
                build();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addResource("hibernate-mappings/HierarchyLevel.hbm.xml");
        configuration.addResource("hibernate-mappings/HierarchyFilter.hbm.xml");
        configuration.addResource("hibernate-mappings/AuditLog.hbm.xml");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class",
                "thread");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder =
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        serviceRegistryBuilder.applySetting(Environment.DATASOURCE, dataSource);
        serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =
                serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        if (sessionFactory != null) {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
        if (dataSource != null) {
            dataSource.shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Before
    public final void startTransaction() {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    @After
    public final void rollBack() {
        session.flush();
        Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
        transaction.rollback();
    }
}
```

I am forced to call `SessionFactory.openSession()` instead but then I won't be able to use my DAOs with the same `SessionFactory` because they all call `getCurrentSession()`. So I won't be able to benefit from the already coded data handling functionality.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works OK when setting up the `Configuration` object using a traditional `hibernate.cfg.xml` using the `SpringSessionContext` as for production like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</property>
    <!-- property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property-->
    <mapping resource="hibernate-mappings/AccessRight.hbm.xml" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and loading that up in the test, but overwriting the `session context` like this:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure(
            "hibernate-mappings/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class",
            "thread");
```

So there is something going on in the background when Hibernate sets itself up with its `hibernate.cfg.xml` that is required.